# Correct way to use the Articles: a, an, the

Tags: articles

So, is there any way to master the use of articles. I do basically know where to use them but I think I might be overusing. Is there a way to limit the usage -- basically, I want to know where not to use them, in what circumstances?

Comment: This is a broad question without a straightforward answer. What resources have you already consulted on the topic, and what do they still leave you confused about?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say it's "overuse", but the article in your very first sentence above is totally unnecessary. So is the word ***so***, which doesn't mean anything there, whereas the question mark at the end if a question ***is*** necessary. So you *could* have started by asking ***Is there any way to master use of articles**?* To which the answer is *There is no quick and easy way to learn everything about the use of articles in English. It's **complex***. So you'll have to narrow things down and ask about some *specific* aspect you're having trouble with.

Comment: Where do you use them or not use them? Your question calls for us to do ""all the work" and you don't even help us to help you. There are a few tricks to using them.

Comment: It depends on the situation, and I think this will be covered by most language methods or grammars. It may also depend on the variety of English. In AE, for example, we would drop the article when talking about an item in general, in the plural form, e.g. "Bicycles are expensive" for example. If you are talking about specific bicycles that are in a conversation, though, you must use the article: "The bicycles are expensive." In some grammars, such words are called "determiners" instead, which may be more accurate terminology, since determiners include others words like "these", "those", etc.

Comment: @Brandin There can also be: A bicyle is expensive, when talking to someone.